# Probability question concerning the sum of a pair of dice

Tags: probability

If I tossed a pair of dice and the sum on the uppermost faces are recorded.

What is the probability that I will throw a sum of 9 before I throw I sum of 7?

I've established that the probability of getting a sum of 9 is $\frac{4}{36}$ OR $\frac{1}{9}$

And I've established that the probability of getting a sum of 7 is $\frac{6}{36}$ OR $\frac{1}{6}$

But, I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Can you solve the problem if 7 and 9 were the only two possible outcomes? Can you reduce to that case?

Answer (score 1):

Rolling a sum of 9 is from [3,6], [6,3], [4, 5], [5,4], and rolling a sum of 7 is [3,4], [4,3], [2, 5], [5,2], [1, 6], [6, 1]. The total number of possible solutions for all is 4 + 6 = 10. Rolling a sum of 9 has 4 possibilities. Hence, 4/10 = 2/5, or 40%.